# Striped pattern for overlapping features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, fill

I am trying to generate language maps for regions with multilinguality. Often, such maps use different colors for different language polygons, and a striped pattern for the overlap area, like here (image links to PDF of that map):

[image: “Ecquador” map from “As línguas amazônicas hoje” (Queixalós & Renault-Lescure 2000)]

I had assumed that this is a frequent enough pattern also in other maps to find a simple way. Is there something more convenient than manually creating every intersection as polygon with a custom Line Pattern Fill (setting the line width to something like 1.5mm and the spacing to 3mm) in the color of the lower of the two polygons to overlay the upper one?

Comment: Are your polygons in different layers or the same one?  What do you mean by "manually"?  If in different layers an intersect or  union would split out the overlap which can then be symbolized with the line pattern fills.  If in the same layer you could use the SAGA polygon self intersect to split out the overlaps, or you could add the layer twice, definition query it for each language, then run an intersect or union to split out the overlaps.

Comment: I have one layer with one multipolygon per language. By “manually” I the process of (1) computing the intersections, in particular where I have multilingual areas one pass of “intersection” is not enough (2) going through each intersection multi-polygon and checking which base polygon is not shown because it is covered and then generating a line pattern for it, again with more complexity where more than 2 languages meet.

Comment: Here's an inelegant approach to look at.  Run the split by attributes tool on your layer to get individual language polygon layers.  Then run a union of them (I see that the latest QGIS has multiple overlay versions of some tools like union but I haven't used it yet) to split out the overlaying areas and put the languages in the attribute table.  Add a new field for symbolizing and use the calculator to fill it with the language or languages in the table.  Then symbolize that using your lines and the categorizing option to get a different line fill for each combo.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a simple fill style for the non overlapping parts. FOr FIll color, use data driven override with an expression like this: `case when "language" = 'language_A' then 'red' else 'blue' end`.
2. Create a new symbol layer of type Geometry generator *above* the one from step 1 for the overlapping parts. Use this expression to create the overlapping part:

   ```
   intersection (
       geometry (
           get_feature (
               @layer,
               'language',  -- change this to match the field name that contains the language information
               'language_A'  -- fill in here the name of your language
           )
       ),
       geometry (
           get_feature (
               @layer,
               'language',  -- change this to match the field name that contains the language information
               'language_B'  -- fill in here the name of your language
           )
       )
   )
   ```
3. Set the Fill style for this symbol layer to `Line Pattern Fill`, set the color for the first language (red). Choose a value like 2 for the `stroke width` and be sure to make the value for `Spacing` double of it (here: 4).
4. Then add another `Line Pattern Fill` for the second language (blue). Repeat steps from above, but additonally, set offset to the same value as stroke width (2).

[image]